# Separate by semicolon wmic loop

Tags: batch-file

Getting drives in variable

```
LogicalDisk = "c:\d:\"
```

now i want to get drives separated by *semicolon;*

like `LogicalDisk = "c:\;d:\;e:\;f:\"`

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name /format:value')  do (
    set "LogicalDisk=!LogicalDisk!%%d\"
    )
    echo %LogicalDisk%

endlocal
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name /format:value')  do (
 set "LogicalDisk=!LogicalDisk!%%d\;"
)
set"LogicalDisk=%LogicalDisk:~0,-1%"
echo %LogicalDisk%
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name /format:value')  do (
set "LogicalDisk=!LogicalDisk!%%d\"
)
set"LogicalDisk=%LogicalDisk:\=\;%"
set"LogicalDisk=%LogicalDisk:~0,-1%"
echo %LogicalDisk%
```

Comment: well at the end there is additional semicolon c:\;d:\; which need to strip out